# Android provider Entity Relationship diagrams?

Tags: android

Has anybody ever seen an entity relationship diagram of Android's provider databases?

I'm getting into the contacts database, and a bit into the media database. Boy would a diagram showing how the tables relate to each other really help.

Comment: I love optimism!  What makes you so special?  Why can't you suffer with the inadequate documentation like the rest of us?  ;)  (Good luck)

Comment: Strange comment, the question was whether you had seen such a diagram, not whether you hadn't. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Hmm, it was a joke (and some sarcasm). Clearly backfired.  I too would love to see a diagram.  It was a poor attempt to empathise with you and to lament the state of the Android platform documentation.  Apologies.

Comment: No worries, I'm digging into this, and will post something when done.

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be any such thing in the public domain. Very unfortunate, as this can lead to app developers not grasping the databases and putting the wrong data in the database.

I have had some success in investigating the databases on the emulator. In order to do this, the database files were copied from the emulator to my desktop, and then opened in a firefox add-on for Sqlite3. Android have added their own collator to some tables (PHONEBOOK), so the sqlite browser does complain a bit.
The 2 databases I have looked at are on the android device emulator in the following locations:

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases for media databases

/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases for contacts
```

It did take quite a bit of fumbling around to get the files across, in the process, learnt that the adb shell has no cp (copy) command, but does adb pull, which can be used to copy a file from one location to another on the device, that coupled with trying `chmod 777 *.db` seemed to do the trick. The final step was to use eclipse's pull file from the device utility to get the database files across to my desktop.

This is by no means an expert's guide, but it looks like this is all there is at present.

It's much easier to look at the databases, and their structure on a desktop, than with the adb command line shell.